# Django Group Entries by Month

Tags: django

I'm simply trying to group entries in my Data.active_objects that occur in the same month and year. I would like if entries sharing the same month and year would be annotated with the number of occurrences in Data.active_objects

Data.active_objects has a few entries with the same month values in 'ts_create'

What I've tried so far is

```
test = Data.active_objects.annotate(ts_create__count=Count(TruncMonth('ts_create), distinct=True)
```

However, this does not produce results that I would expect as every entry in Data.active_objects has an annotated value 'ts_create__count' of 1 even when the entries occur in the same month

Comment: So you want to count the number of `Data` per month?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**`TruncMonth`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#django.db.models.functions.TruncMonth) to truncate the `ts_create` to the start of a month, and then annotate with the number of items with:

```
from django.db.models import Count
from django.db.models.functions import TruncMonth

Data.objects.values(
    month=TruncMonth('ts_create')
).annotate(
    count=Count('pk')
).order_by('month')
```

This will produce a `QuerySet` of dictionaries with `month` and `count` as keys, like:

```
<QuerySet [
    {'month': date(2022, 1, 1), 'count': 14},
    {'month': date(2022, 2, 1), 'count': 25},
    {'month': date(2022, 3, 1), 'count': 13},
    {'month': date(2022, 4, 1), 'count': 2}
]>
```

Comment: As far as I can tell this works. However, I am still somewhat confused. How does getting the values for an attribute, then counting the primary key solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from django.db.models.functions import ExtractMonth, ExtractYear

test = Data.active_objects.annotate(year=ExtractYear('ts_create'),
                                month = ExtractMonth('ts_create')).values('year','month').annotate(total=Count('id'))
```